# Swift - Cannot pass dictionary into custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

I have a controller which has a table with four cells. Each of these custom cells contain another table, in which I display row data.
Take a look at the screenshot:
[image: Swift - Cannot pass dictionary into custom cell]

Here is how I init custom cell and pass data to it:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell! {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("DashCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! DashCell
    cell.dictionary = dataArray[indexPath.row] as Dictionary!
    cell.sectionTitle = sectionTitles[indexPath.row]
    cell.titlesArray = columnTitles[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}
```

And here is my custom cell code:

```
@objc(DashCell) class DashCell: UITableViewCell, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableViewInsideCell: UITableView!

var dictionary: Dictionary<String, String>?
var sectionTitle: String?
var titlesArray: Array<String>?

var screenWidth: CGFloat!
var data: Array<String> = []

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String!) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    println("Dictionary in cell \(dictionary)")

    let firstColumn: String = dictionary!["FirstColumn"]!
    let secondColumn: String = dictionary!["SecondColumn"]!
    let thirdColumn: String = dictionary!["ThirdColumn"]!
    let fourthColumn: String = dictionary!["FourthColumn"]!
    let fifthColumn: String = dictionary!["FifthColumn"]!
    var sixthColumn: String? = dictionary!["SixthColumn"]!
    var sevenColumn: String? = dictionary!["SeventhColumn"]!

    data.append(firstColumn)
    data.append(secondColumn)
    data.append(thirdColumn)
    data.append(fourthColumn)
    data.append(fifthColumn)
    if sixthColumn != nil {
        data.append(sixthColumn!)
    }
    if sevenColumn != nil {
        data.append(sevenColumn!)
    }

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    screenWidth = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
}

func addTitleLabel(text: String, withOffset offset: CGFloat) -> UILabel {
    var label: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(15 + offset, 23, screenWidth / CGFloat(titlesArray!.count), 17))
    label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(10.0)
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    label.text = text
    return label
}

func addRowLabel(text: String, withOffset offset: CGFloat) -> UILabel {
    var label: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(15 + offset, 2, screenWidth / CGFloat(data.count) - 10, 17))
    label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(9.0)
    label.numberOfLines = 1
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    label.text = text
    return label
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 8
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    var headerView: UIView = UIView()
    var sectionTitleLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(15, 3, screenWidth, 20))
    sectionTitleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)
    sectionTitleLabel.numberOfLines = 1
    sectionTitleLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    sectionTitleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    var lableText: String = sectionTitle!
    sectionTitleLabel.text = lableText.uppercaseString
    sectionTitleLabel.textColor = UIColor(red: 110 / 255.0, green: 110 / 255.0, blue: 115 / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    sectionTitleLabel.text!.uppercaseString
    headerView.addSubview(sectionTitleLabel)
    var offset: CGFloat = screenWidth / CGFloat(titlesArray!.count)
    for var j: Int = 0; j < titlesArray!.count; j++ {
        let headerLabel: UILabel = self.addTitleLabel(titlesArray![j], withOffset: offset * CGFloat(j))
        headerView.addSubview(headerLabel)
    }
    return headerView
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 40
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 22
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var CellIdentifier: String = "Cell"
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(CellIdentifier) as? UITableViewCell
    if cell == nil {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier)
    }

    var offset: CGFloat = screenWidth / CGFloat(data.count)
    for var j = 0; j < data.count; j++ {
        let string: String = data[j] as String
        var label: UILabel = self.addRowLabel(string, withOffset: offset * CGFloat(j))
        cell!.contentView.addSubview(label)
    }
    return cell!
}
```

The problem is that `dictionary` variable always comes nil, although `sectionTitle` and `titlesArray` are filled with data. Why is it so?

**[UPDATE]** The dictionary is set like this in parent view controller in viewDidLoad:

```
    var one: Dictionary<String, String> = ["FirstColumn" : "R-L-1776-07-2015-1", "SecondColumn" : "Aaron Bloch", "ThirdColumn" : "$5,000.00", "FourthColumn" : "153 E 32 STREET", "FifthColumn" : "Open"]
    var two: Dictionary<String, String> = ["FirstColumn" : "R-L-1776-07-2015-4", "SecondColumn" : "Test User", "ThirdColumn" : "$500.00", "FourthColumn" : "635 W 42nd St", "FifthColumn" : "Yes"]
    var three: Dictionary<String, String> = ["FirstColumn" : "Bruno", "SecondColumn" : "Ricciotti", "ThirdColumn" : "bruno@bondnewyork.com", "FourthColumn" : "917-699-7151", "FifthColumn" : "Some text"]
    var four: Dictionary<String, String> = ["FirstColumn" : "#448438", "SecondColumn" : "Resid. Rent", "ThirdColumn" : "$345.00", "FourthColumn" : "Studio", "FifthColumn" : "1", "SixthColumn" : "Hamilton Heights", "SeventhColumn" : "Aaron Bloch"]
    dataArray = [one, two, three, four]
```

`dataArray` is inited like this:

```
var dataArray: Array<Dictionary<String, String>> = []
```

Comment: If its a Swift question, why do you tag it with objective-c?

Comment: Can you tell me where did you set the dictionary value?

Comment: @Siam please see updated question

Comment: Have you already solved your problem, I have no idea why the dictionary variable is nil